Setting a `sentry` property on the Next.js config is no longer supported
I am getting this warning in my console for my nextjs setup:

[@sentry/nextjs] Setting a sentry property on the Next.js config is no longer supported. Please use the sentrySDKOptions argument of withSentryConfig instead.

"@sentry/core": "^8.6.0",
"@sentry/nextjs": "^8.6.0",

Now I am not sure what that means. my next.config.mjs looks like this:
export default withSentryConfig(nextConfig, {
    org: "my-org",
    project: "my-project",

    authToken: process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
    silent: true,
    widenClientFileUpload: true,
    hideSourceMaps: true,
    disableLogger: true,
    automaticVercelMonitors: true,
});

Is that not right?

Your nextConfig object likely looks something like this:
const nextConfig = {
  // some properties...
  sentry: {
    // ...
  }
}

The Sentry SDK v8 no longer uses the sentry property on nextConfig and you should pass options directly to withSentryConfig instead.

if I have to pass properties to nextConfig then i cant use withSentryConfig right? In the docs it says I should use withSentryConfig

Ah i get it, i still had a sentry entry in nextConfig which is not allowed!
